# HttpClient using existing TcpStream

Tags: c#, httpclient, tcpclient

Assuming I create a TcpStream object:

```
var tcpClient = new TcpClient("host", 443);
var tcpStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
```

Is it possible to use the connected stream as the underlying transport for an HttpClient?
Pseudo'ish, meaning:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient(tcpStream); // Pseudo-code
```

So the httpClient would not open a new connection, but use the existing socket to codec message and transport them, thanks

Comment: You want to do HTTP over TCP.  See following : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155282/TCP-Server-Client-Communication-Implementation.  HTTPClient requires a new connection for each request/response.  An HTTPSocket keeps the connection open after each request/response.

Comment: Well, basically yes but without the super extra complexity in that doc. I could have encoded the http headers and body on the wire and craft my http message, but then I would also need to decode the response and deal with all the http RFC... I'd like to make use of all this that is already implemented in HttpClient, only my problem is that HttpClient manages its own TCP stack, but I would like to provide it with my own pre-made connection and let it skip the TCP-SYN part

Comment: The c# source code is found here : https://referencesource.microsoft.com/.  You can copy the code and modify as required : https://referencesource.microsoft.com/